# Java integer problems, how to set constraints properly and set unallowable integer

Tags: java

So , as you can see,I tried to set up some loop here , an two if statements, I used nested for loops in java script so I thought this may work, not having much luck.

Observe the third set, i made it from `1000 - 10000`, so it will be from `1000-9999`, because, I don't know how to make it from `0000-9999`, with it needing to print those `0` ( PHONE NUMBER)

I am a new student to programming, so please be really clear and simple with me, thanks.

**GOAL**

1. xxx-xxx-xxxx
2. 1st set =  3 number , cannot have 8 or 9
3. 2nd set, not greater than 742
4. Third set = 0000 -9999

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.lang.Math;


public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Random  rand= new Random();

        int a1 = rand.nextInt(7);
        int a2 = rand.nextInt(7);
        int a3 =rand.nextInt(7);


        int b = rand.nextInt(741);
       int c = rand.nextInt(9999);

        while (b.length<4)
        {
            b (string)=  "0"+ c ;
        }



        while (c.length()<4)
        {
            c (string)= "0"+ c ;
        }


        System.out.println(a1 +""+ a2+ ""+ +a3+ "-" + b + "-" + c );


    }


    }
```

Comment: so you are facing problem with 1st set only, right?

Comment: well, I kind of cheated the 2nd and third, because I dont know how to get it 000-0000, if it is less than the 100 or 1000, its a phone number right.

Comment: So you are asking how to print those 0s? Or are you asking how to use nested for loops, or what? What is your question exactly?

Comment: in first set, the constraint is not working, in 2nd and third, if you have a solution to those constraints, on how to set it better, its very good.

Comment: I need to have a better way to set his unallowable integer, an for loop to make it ++

Comment: `c (string)= "0"+ c ;`  Does that compile? What does it do?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this for **a**:

```
int array[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
String st = String.format("%d%d%d", array[(int)(Math.random()*8)] , array[(int)(Math.random()*8)] , array[(int)(Math.random()*8)]);
```

And to show the output in console:

```
System.out.println(st + "-" + b + "-" + c );
```

Comment: does not solve constraint problem, not concise, overly complicated, thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Hey mate this is what I can offer you so far:

```
    import java.util.Random;

    public class HelpYou {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            HelpYou helpYou = new HelpYou();
            String a1 = helpYou.generateFirstSet();
            String a2 = helpYou.generateSecondSet();
            String a3 = helpYou.generateThirdSet();
            System.out.println("GOAL: XXX-XXX-XXXX");
            System.out.println("RESULT: "+a1 + "-" + a2 + "-" + a3);

        }

        public String generateFirstSet() {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int a1;
            String firstSet = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                a1 = rand.nextInt(7);
                firstSet = firstSet.concat("" + a1);
            }
            return firstSet;
        }

        public String generateSecondSet() {
            String secondSet = "";
            do {
                secondSet = generateFirstSet();
            // This while solves your constraint :)
            } while (Integer.parseInt(secondSet) > 742);

            return secondSet;
        }

    public String generateThirdSet() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int a1;
        String thirdSet = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            a1 = rand.nextInt(9);
            thirdSet = thirdSet.concat("" + a1);
        }
        return thirdSet;
    }

}
```

Think this is what you wanted hope it helps you, thats an object oriented approach, 0 complexity, if you need me to clarify you anything or any questions feel free.

Also the way you are trying to get to GOAL is not possible with int, because the random function will never give you a 0 something number (093 or 0094), it can only give you 1+ numbers (101 or 10 or 1000 or so). What I mean with this is that `number = rand.nextInt(9999);` will never give you a 0 something number (0000 or so). So you will need to build the second and third set by your self like you did with first set, like so (this is a simplier solution):

```
import java.util.Random;

public class HelpYouSimplier {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int a1 = rand.nextInt(7);
        int a2 = rand.nextInt(7);
        int a3 = rand.nextInt(7);
        String b = "";

        do {
          int b1 = rand.nextInt(7);
          int b2 = rand.nextInt(4);
          int b3 = rand.nextInt(2);
          b = "" + b1 + b2 + b3;
        } while (Integer.parseInt(b) > 742);

        // Variables for third set
        int c1 = rand.nextInt(9);
        int c2 = rand.nextInt(9);
        int c3 = rand.nextInt(9);
        int c4 = rand.nextInt(9);

        String c = "" + c1 + c2 + c3 + c4;

        System.out.println(a1 + "" + a2 + "" + +a3 + "-" + b + "-" + c);

    }

}
```